# How to add timepicker in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to add timepicker in my MVC Application. I added the plugin. But the script is not loading after adding the timepicker .

Can any one please help  me?

View page:

```
 <div>
        <input type="text" id="timepick "/>
    </div>
    @section Scripts
    {
  <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
                debugger;
                $("#timepick").timepicker();

            });

        </script>
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do not add both the standard and minified versions of the same file. Have you included `jquery-{version}.js??

Comment: Make sure you load jQuery (>= 1.7) before loading timepicker library.

Comment: Is there any other way or link to follow to add time picker in MVC Application @StephenMuecke

Comment: You need to edit you question with the relevant details (not put it in comments). You should also indicate what errors your getting in the browser console (if any)

Answer (score 0):

As, you mentioned that script are not loading. This may be happening due to `Scripts` section not available on layout page or maybe you are not using any layout for the existing view.

Can you please verify that layout page contains `RenderSection` tag or not? If not, then please include below line:

```
@RenderSection ("Scripts", required: false)
```

Please let me know if problem persist.